# compute determinant from LU decomposition in lapack

Tags: lapack

Lapack, most probably, doesn't have any routine for computing determinant. However we can compute it using either LU, QR or SVD decomposition. I prefer to use LU decomposition. Now lapack uses some dgetrf subroutine to factorize a matrix A into PLU format with some IPIV array. I don't have much idea how to deal with this information. To compute the determinant, I just multiply diagonal elements of U matrix. But what is L and U in PLU format and how to extract them. I am programming in C.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lapack's [`dgetrf()`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-3.1.1-html/dgetrf.f.html) computes a `A=P*L*U` decomposition for a general M-by-N matrix A. Assuming an invertible square matrix A, its determinant can be computed as a product:

- `U` is an upper triangular matrix. Hence, its determinant is the product of the diagonal elements, which happens to be the diagonal elements of the output `A`. Indeed, see [how the output A is defined](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d3/d6a/dgetrf_8f_source.html):

  > On exit, the factors L and U from the factorization `A = P*L*U`; the unit diagonal elements of L are not stored.
- `L` is a lower triangular matrix featuring unit diagonal elements which are not stored. Hence, its determinant is always 1.
- `P` is a permutation matrix coded as a product of transpositions( i.e. 2-cycles or swap) . Indeed, see [`dgetri()`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/df/da4/dgetri_8f_source.html) to understand how it is used. Hence, its determinant is either 1 or -1, depending on whether the number of transpositions is even or odd. As a result, the determinant of `P` can be computed as:

  ```
  int j;
  double detp=1.;
  for( j=0;j<n;j++){
      if(j+1!=ipiv[j]){
          // j+1 : following feedback of ead : ipiv is from Fortran, hence starts at 1.
          // hey ! This is a transpose !
          detp=-detp;
      }
  }
  ```

The complexity of this method is dominated by the cost of the Gaussian elimination using partial pivoting, that is O(2/3n^3).

You will likely turn to full pivoting using [`dgetc2()`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-3.1.1-html/dgetc2.f.html) or QR decomposition to improve the accuracy. As signaled in [Algebraic and Numerical Techniques for the Computation of Matrix Determinants](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.110.791&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Pan et. al., combining equation 4.8, 4.9 and proposition 4.1, the final error on the determinant likely scales like `ed=(a+eps*a*n^4)^{n-1}*eps*an^5=a^n*(1+eps*n^4)^{n-1}*n^5*eps` where `eps` is the precision of double (about 1e-13), a is the largest magnitude of all elements in matrix A and n is the size of the matrix. It means that the computed determinant is not very significant for "large" matrices: see tables, it particular the relative error as PLU decomposition is used! The article also provides an algorithm to track the propagation of error and produce a better estimate of the error.

You can also try the [Faddeev–Le Verrier algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faddeev%E2%80%93LeVerrier_algorithm)...

Comment: because ipiv has values `1...n` it should be probably `j+1!=ipiv[j]` see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/50285530/5769463

Comment: Thanks @ead for your feedback: my answer had to be corrected.

Comment: Machine epsilon for double precision is 2.22e-16, using the definition in C, C++, Fortran, etc., not 1e-13. (Some including LAPACK define eps as half that, 1.11e-16, which is unit roundoff.)

Answer (score 2):

L is a unit diagonal matrix so its determinant is always unity. For `P` it is either `1` or `-1` depending on the odd/even number of permutations but `ipiv` is a swap array not the permutation array so you can convert the following simple Python loop to C

```
det = 1

for i in range(len(ipiv)):
    det *= u(i,i)
    if ipiv[i] != i:
        det *= -1
```

But note that multiplication can both overflow or underflow if the conditioning of the matrix is problematic in terms of conditioning. Instead just use SVD.

Comment: What is u(i,i) in PLU format matrix. Is it the diagonal elements of PLU matrix ?

Comment: @user402940 Ah yes sorry diagonals of the U matrix

Answer (score 0):

Fortran code:

```
!LU decomposition
lda = n
call dgetrf( n, n, A,lda, ipiv, info)
    
!det_U
det_U = ONE
do i=1,n
  det_U =  det_U*A(i,i)
enddo

!det_L
det_L = ONE

!det_P
det_P = ONE
do i=1,n
  if (ipiv(i)/=i)then
      det_P = -det_P
  endif
enddo

!det
det = det_P*det_L*det_U
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

C version:

```
/*
 Compile and excute with:
    $ gcc det.c -o det -llapacke
    $ ./det 
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <lapacke.h>
#define dim 3

int main() {
    int n = dim; 
    int lda = n;

    printf("Initial matrix:\n");
    double A[dim*dim] = { 3.0, -1.0,  2.0, 
                         -3.0,  3.0, -1.0, 
                          6.0,  0.0,  4.0 };
    int ipiv[dim];
    int info;

    // Print matrix A
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("  [");
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("%f", A[i * n + j]);
            if (j < n - 1) printf(", ");
        }
        printf("]");
        if (i < n - 1) printf(",\n");
    }

    // Perform LU-decomposition to get ipiv values
    info = LAPACKE_dgetrf(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, n, n, A, lda, ipiv);
    if (info < 0) {
        printf("\nError: Argument %d had an illegal value\n", -info);
        return -1;
    } else if (info > 0) {
        printf("\nError: Matrix is singular\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Calculate the determinant
    double determinant = 1.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        determinant *= A[i * n + i];
    }
    int sign = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (ipiv[i] != i + 1) {
            sign = -sign;
        }
    }
    determinant *= sign;

    // Print the result
    printf("\nDeterminant: %lf\n", determinant);

    return 0;
}
```