# QR factorization from lapack subroutine dgeqrf not working in C

Tags: lapack

I want to find diagonal elements of R matrix obtained from QR-decomposition of A matrix as A=QR using lapack. I tried lapack dgeqrf subroutine but it is giving back the same matrix A i.e. input and output matrices are same. How to find R matrix and its diagonals ? I can't figure out what is going wrong with this code. I am programming in C.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
void dgeqrf_(int *rows, int *cols, double *matA, int *LDA, double *TAU, double *WORK, int *LWORK, int *INFO);
int main()
{
    int rows=3;
    int cols=3;
    double *matA=malloc(sizeof(double)*rows*cols);

    matA[0]=10;
    matA[1]=20;
    matA[2]=10;
    matA[3]=40;
    matA[4]=20;
    matA[5]=50;
    matA[6]=70;
    matA[7]=30;
    matA[8]=20;

    for(int i=0; i<rows*cols; i++)
    {
        printf("%f ",matA[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    int LDA=rows;
    int INFO;
    double *WORK=malloc(sizeof(double)*2);
    int LWORK=-1;
    int rowcolmin=rows;
    if(rowcolmin>cols)
    {
        rowcolmin=cols;
    }
    double *TAU=malloc(sizeof(double)*rowcolmin);
    dgeqrf_(&rows, &cols, matA, &LDA, TAU, WORK, &LWORK, &INFO);
    for(int i=0; i<rows*cols; i++)
    {
        printf("%f ",matA[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    free(WORK);
    free(TAU);
    free(matA);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix `matA` is not modified because LAPACK's [`dgeqrf()`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-3.1.1-html/dgeqrf.f.html) is called using a value of -1 for the argument `LWORK`. This correspond to a workspace query:

> If LWORK = -1, then a workspace query is assumed; the routine
>             only calculates the optimal size of the WORK array, returns
>             this value as the first entry of the WORK array, and no error
>             message related to LWORK is issued by XERBLA.

**Indeed, the usual way to use `dgeqrf()` and many other routines from LAPACK is to call them twice: once for the workspace query and once for the actual computation of the result.** For instance, the C interface to LAPACK wraps `dgeqrf()` in [`lapacke__dgeqrf()`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d3/dd8/lapacke__dgeqrf_8c_source.html), which calls `lapacke__dgeqrf_work()` twice for this very reason.

Here is how your code could be modified:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
void dgeqrf_(int *rows, int *cols, double *matA, int *LDA, double *TAU, double *WORK, int *LWORK, int *INFO);
int main()
{
    int i;
    int rows=3;
    int cols=3;
    double *matA=malloc(sizeof(double)*rows*cols);

    matA[0]=1;
    matA[1]=2;
    matA[2]=4;
    matA[3]=1;
    matA[4]=3;
    matA[5]=9;
    matA[6]=1;
    matA[7]=4;
    matA[8]=16;

    for(i=0; i<rows*cols; i++)
    {
        printf("%f ",matA[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    int LDA=rows;
    int INFO;

    int rowcolmin=rows;
    if(rowcolmin>cols)
    {
        rowcolmin=cols;
    }

    double *TAU=malloc(sizeof(double)*rowcolmin);
    int LWORK=-1;
    // since the value of LWORK is -1, this is a workspace query.
    // it only return the optimum size of work in work[0].
    double lwork2;    
    dgeqrf_(&rows, &cols, matA, &LDA, TAU, &lwork2, &LWORK, &INFO);
    // allocate work using the optimal size
    int lwork3=(int)lwork2;
    double *WORK=malloc(sizeof(double)*lwork3);
    // perform the QR factorization
    dgeqrf_(&rows, &cols, matA, &LDA, TAU, WORK, &lwork3, &INFO);
    if(INFO !=0){fprintf(stderr,"QR factorization failed, error code %d\n",INFO);exit(1);}

    for(i=0; i<rows*cols; i++)
    {
        printf("%f ",matA[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");


    // for instance, the determinant is...
    if(cols==rows){
        // det of R
        double det=1;
        for (i=0;i<cols;i++){
            det*=matA[i*cols+i];
        }
        // det of Q, Householder algorithm
        if(cols%2==0){
            det*=-1;
        }
        printf("det is %g\n",det);
    }
    free(WORK);
    free(TAU);
    free(matA);
    return 0;
}
```

It is compiled by `gcc main.c -o main -llapack -lblas -lm`.

Given the question you asked, entitled [compute determinant from LU decomposition in lapack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47315471/compute-determinant-from-lu-decomposition-in-lapack/47319635#47319635) , the computation of the determinant is added at the end of the code. The matrix `matA` is now a [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix), so as to easily check the correctness of the result.